# Absolute positioned dropdown within fixed header not working in IE 7,8

Tags: html, css

I have a [layout that works](https://github.com/bruffridge/AppLayout) that I wanted to add the ability to fix the header to the top. When I add the following to fix the header, my dropdown menu no longer is visible in IE 7 & 8.

```
div#top {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

I tried setting higher z-indexes on all the parent elements of the dropdown which didn't work. It shows in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari just not IE 7&8, haven't tried IE9. I have a fiddle where you can see the results.

http://jsfiddle.net/tDhBq/

http://jsfiddle.net/tDhBq/embedded/result/ Full Screen

Comment: I ran the js script through jslint and got a bunch of errors...

Comment: The js should be pretty tight. I took it unmodified from Twitter's Bootstrap project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it took me a while to find the problem. In my original post I wasn't showing all the code. In my styles for `div#top` was a `z-index` property that I left out. Removing the `z-index` property from `div#top` fixed the issue in IE8 but the problem still existed in IE7. Removing the `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient` which I was using to set the gradient from `div#top` fixed the issue in IE7. Not sure why the gradient caused an issue with `position: fixed` and not with `position: static`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with my menu with `position:fixed` and a dropdown menu with `position:absolute` from twitter bootstrap.

It seems that in IE7–9 the property `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient` on the menu is reducing the menu to a `height:auto`. So I couldn't see my dropdown menu like you.

I deleted it, and it works fine now!